# Is there a difference between therefore and "for this reason"?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, transitions

> They acknowledge that tasks that attempt to test a certain executive function such as memory have some variability amongst them, for this reason they used factor analysis

I know the sentence contains some jargon, so I will try to explain the logic as best as I can. The variability among the tasks is why they use factor analysis, however it most certainly is not the only thing they could have done. Is there a difference between *therefore* and *for this reason* in such a situation? My intuition tells me that *therefore* implies more certainty that this is the only possible effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be used in most contexts. **For this reason** has an effect of sounding like a person chose to do something. **Therefore** has a more analytical effect, as in an opinion in an essay.

However, they are interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you, yes this sounds about right.